# How do you turn sprites into objects , for mutable arrays?

Tags: iphone, object, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, sprite

I have a mutable array which stores sprites but the problem is that the sprites aren't objects and need to be created into objects so that they can be stored in the array, i am using cocos2d. Here is my code so far.

```
    NSMutableArray  *sprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; int spritecount = 0;
    [sprites insertObject:red1 atIndex:spritecount++];
    [sprites insertObject:red2 atIndex:spritecount++];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about `CCSprites`, they DO inherit from `NSObject`, so you should be able to insert them in a `NSMutableArray`.